# how to align spike's position left and right in beautytips jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip, beautytips

I am using beautytips jquery plugin [here is the demo link](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) for one of my project. I have an image and when clicked on it, it pops up a Div and shows the relative contents but the spike's position is always in the middle. I wanted to change this spike's position left and right for other images but I don't know how to do this. I am also attaching the screen-shot for this middle spike position. Please help me to align this spike in left and right too.[image: here is the screen shot]

[image: like this]

Answer (score 2):

Since this doesn't seem to be possible with your tooltip (see below for explanation) choice and you are not stuck with this option only check out this tooltop called [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/):

Specially check out the options of positioning it has [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/corner#), the top left suits you perfectly in my opionion, I hope it helps, see screenshot:

[image]

Also, there are many other helpful plugins out there, see a [list here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/), maybe you prefer any of them...

---

Edit I think I found what the problem was, the length of the spike is not long enough and because of that it is simply not showing the change in the centerPoint, that unfortunately I think it is the plugin was made, chec this example out:

http://jsfiddle.net/43Acn/5/

[image]

Now if I only change the length of the spike see it here http://jsfiddle.net/43Acn/6/ you will see this:

[image]

Note that the only change was `spikeLength: 30,` to `spikeLength: 5,`...

---

---

I don't know whether you want to align the spike with respect to the bubble or to the image, if it is to the bubble then you must use this parameter:

```
centerPointX: .5,
```

Check the [source code](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/jquery.bt.js) and at the very bottom you will see the default option for this parameter is .5 this means 50%. if you want 30% (of the bubble) you should use:

```
centerPointX: .3,
```

You can also use `centerPointY`if you wish to.

Se a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/43Acn/).

Try changing `centerPointY: .9,` to `centerPointY: .1,` to see the changes...

Comment: Hi Trufa, I have uploaded one more image above. I hope this will help you to understand what I want to design. I tried the property centerPointX but does not work. Can you please tell me the solution.

Comment: Hi Trufa here is the link of my html file : http://jeewanaryal.web44.net/beautytips/beautytips/baloonTest.html

Comment: @soflover please try to make a jsfiddle like I did since your javascript if minified and I can't read it nor show you what you want to modify...

Comment: here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jeewanaryal/hwtTK/3/ . I am trying to make 3 positions for the spike: left, middle and right. can you please check this code.

Comment: @soflover please see my edit! Unfortunately I think there are no much ways around it, the problem is with the length of the spike...

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hwtTK/4/) is your example with the changed property, note that the change is almost unnoticeable also see [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/hwtTK/5/) and you'll see better the change with a longer spike...

Comment: I have to leave now I'll be home in a couple of hours and try to help you out but now I'll add another edit with an option, please check it out...

Comment: Hi Traufa, thanks a lot. I am checking your modifications and also trying to see the jquery.bt.js file. I will post if I get other solution. Take care ...

Comment: @soflover great also take a look at my last edit and see if it helps.

Comment: hey Trufa, finally I got the solution, thanks for your help. Your Edits in jsfiddle helped me finally... superb dude, thanks :-)

Comment: Hi Trufa, I did not use that plug in. Yesterday, I wrote my own code from scratch for my requirement and that just worked for me. You can see the result here: http://jeewanaryal.web44.net/mhf/WebContent%20july13/home.html currently I am working for this company and I need to make that feature in the home page. I did not use any plugin for this. For example click any of the 7 images just below the slider

Comment: please don't be sad for closing this Q/A. I am very thankful to you for your answers :-)

Comment: @soflover glad you fixed that. Anyway please consider that this is a public forum and if you accept the answer it will show that it answers the original question (which I think it does no matter what you ended up doing). Anyway that is completely up to you :) cheers!